# Angular2: Check if global Service Var has changed in child Class

Tags: angular, ionic2

I have a two tab Ionic 2/Angular2 app that displays data for a large group comprised of many smaller groups. The user can choose to see the data on the two different tabs for the overall master group or for specific groups by choosing that in a right side menu that slides out and provides all the options (each individual group or the master group).

I maintain that list in a global service provider so that if it changes, both tabs can see what is currently selected. This is done by binding the variable to the html. For example I header on both tabs that displays the currently selected view like this:

```
<ion-navbar greenTheme>
  <button menuToggle>
      <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
  </button>
  <ion-title>{{globalService.currentTitle}}</ion-title>
  <ion-buttons menuToggle='right' end>
      <button>
          <ion-icon name='add'></ion-icon>
      </button>
  </ion-buttons>
</ion-navbar>
```

In the main app component (app.ts/.html), I display the side menu and the list that I pull from the global service. If the user selects a new group on the side menu, the app.ts listener function changes the var in the global service provider like this:

```
**app.html**
<ion-menu side='right' type='overlay' [content]="content">
    <ion-content class='right-side-menu'>
        <ion-list no-lines>
            <ion-item menuClose='right' *ngFor='let d of globalService.getGroups()' (click)='sendGroup(d)' class='work-group'>
                {{d}}
            </ion-item>
        </ion-list>    
    </ion-content>
</ion-menu>

**app.ts**
sendGroup(groupName) {
    this.globalService.setCurrentTitle(groupName);
}
```

The tab pages will display the new title because of data binding but the components themselves have no idea if it was changed, and I need to get the more specific data if they choose to view it like that.

**QUESTION:** How do I inform the tab pages that a global service provider var that the pages are displaying has changed?

Comment: Use EventEmitter or RxJS subject instead of object property.

Comment: Its seems like everything I've seen on those deals with sending something from the child to the parent. I'm looking for a child class to detect a change in a parent variable and then spark a function call out of that. So they other way around